# First-time user onboarding with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am implementing a first-time user onboarding in a Xamarin.Forms application like the one on the image below:

[image: onboarding screenshot]

Please, how can I quickly do that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?
[image]

You can use `CarouselView` and `IndicatorView` to achieve it.

Here is layout code.I dont adjust the layout like yours, you can adjust it by yourself, If you want to make Next and Skip Button over float the CarouselView, you can use [AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout)

```
     <StackLayout Margin="10">
        <CarouselView x:Name="myCarouselView" ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                      IndicatorView="indicatorView">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame HasShadow="True"
                               BorderColor="DarkGray"
                               CornerRadius="5"
                               Margin="50"
                               HeightRequest="300"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       FontSize="Large"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                                       HeightRequest="150"
                                       WidthRequest="150"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Location}"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Details}"
                                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       MaxLines="5"
                                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Text="Skip" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
            <Button Text="Next"  Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"></Button>
        </Grid>

        <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                       MaximumVisible="6"
                       Margin="0,0,0,40"
                       IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                       SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is layout bakground code.

```
    public partial class BasicIndicatorViewPage : ContentPage
    {
        int monkeyCount;
        public BasicIndicatorViewPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MonkeysViewModel monkeysViewModel= new MonkeysViewModel();

            monkeyCount = monkeysViewModel.Monkeys.Count;
            BindingContext = monkeysViewModel;
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
            Navigation.RemovePage(this);
        }

        private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (myCarouselView.Position  < monkeyCount-1)
            {
                myCarouselView.Position += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
                Navigation.RemovePage(this);
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is my demo, you can download it.
https://github.com/851265601/XFormsCarouselView-IndicatorViewLoginPage

If you want to put the `indicatorView` and `Button` in the same line like this screenshot.

[image]

You can use this layout(`indicatorView` to the `Grid`).

```
   <StackLayout Margin="10">
        <CarouselView x:Name="myCarouselView" ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                      IndicatorView="indicatorView">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame HasShadow="True"
                               BorderColor="DarkGray"
                               CornerRadius="5"
                               Margin="50"
                               HeightRequest="300"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       FontSize="Large"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                                       HeightRequest="150"
                                       WidthRequest="150"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Location}"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Details}"
                                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       MaxLines="5"
                                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />

                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Text="Skip" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
            <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                       MaximumVisible="6"

                       IndicatorColor="LightGray"
                       SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
            <Button Text="Next"  Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"></Button>
        </Grid>


    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: @Yvder Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue

Answer (score 1):

You could use the offical Xamarin.Forms [CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/) but that's still in preview. You could also potentially look at the [Sharpnado's](https://www.sharpnado.com/) solution with [HorizontalListView](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms/wiki/HorizontalListView-Grid-And-Carousel#carousel-layout). Your third option would be to use [Alex Rainman's CarouselView](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView).